# Angular handle chat private messages

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to deal with chat private messages, so I have 2 services:

- ChatSocket that connects to the server and returns a socket
- ChatHistory that keeps chat messages for each private chat session in a map

In my ChatSocket service I listen for chat private messages and add them to the chat history:

```
.factory('ChatSocket', function (ChatHistory) {
    var socket = io.connect(/* ... */);
    socket.on('priv_msg', function (data) {
        ChatHistory.push(data.user, data.msg);
    });
 });
```

I also use angular ui router so I can have multiple chat "windows" this way:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('app.chat', {
        url: '/chat/:uid',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/chat.html',
                controller: function ($scope, $stateParams, ChatHistory) {
                    $scope.messages = ChatHistory.get($stateParams.uid);
                    /*
                      This returns an array that looks like: 
                      [ 
                          { nickname: 'myself', msg: 'hello' },
                          { nickname: 'someone', msg: 'hi' },
                          { nickname: 'myself', msg: 'how r u?' },
                      ] 
                    */
                }
             }
        }
    }
});
```

This works well, except that since $scope.messages is updated in an external service, I'm really not sure where to call $apply here.

Of course I could add a listener on "priv_msg" event in the controller itself and call $apply there, but this looks a bit overkill:

```
ChatSocket.on('priv_msg', function (data) {
    if (data.user.id == $stateParams.id) {
        $scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

Any idea how to make the messages to be updated? My solution may be correct but I'm kind of new to angular so there may be much better way to achieve that, so I'm totally open to any suggestions / examples.

Comment: there is no specific controller in your service, so there is no scope. what you need is [events](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit).

Comment: so you mean emitting an event in my service and listen to it in each chat controller? This is exactly like listening for "priv_msg" socket event in each controller, isn't it?

Comment: not exactly. you broadcast an event that is specific to the user that got the message. then your ChatController knows, which user owns it and listens only to events for this user. or even user-user combination if you want to have multiple chat windows with multiple other users.

Comment: When you say specific, you mean by its name? like: `$rootScope.$emit('priv_msg_' + user.id)` and then  `$scope.$on('priv_msg_' + $stateParams.id, function () { $scope.$apply(); });`

Comment: yes, something like that. or even $rootScope.$emit('priv_msg_' + user.id + '/' + data.msg.from_user.id);

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks

Comment: no, that's $broadcast. my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make this changes:

```
factory('ChatSocket', function ($rootScope, ChatHistory) {
    var socket = io.connect(/* ... */);
    socket.on('priv_msg', function (data) {
        ChatHistory.push(data.user, data.msg);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('priv_msg/' + data.user.id, data);
    });
 });
```

and

```
controller: function ($scope, $stateParams, ChatHistory) {
    $scope.messages = ChatHistory.get($stateParams.uid);
    // need to set user id to scope for this to work
    $scope.$on('priv_msg/' + $scope.user.id, function(data) {
        $scope.messages.push(data);
    }); 
}
```

not tested though, might be misprints.

Comment: yep, well, I've just tested and it works, but no need for `$scope.messages.push`, it only needs a `$scope.$apply();` because when `ChatHistory` is updated each time either.